# Connecting guitar amp headphone output to audio interface input

Tags: guitar, amplifiers

I have a Squier SP-10 practice amp and a Behringer UMC202 HD audio interface.  I am listening to a guitar piece in Trascribe, trying to learn it. I need to use headphones.  I need to try to connect the headphone out to the usb audio interface input so I can listen to the amp and Transcribe on my PC through the audio interface at the same time.  If I try to connect a guitar cable from the amp headphone output to the audio interface input and listen to the output from the headphone output on the audio interface there is very, very little volume.  Is there some way to make the volume louder.  I know that there is a connection because if I turn the volume to max on the amp and I can barely hear the sound from Transcribe on my PC through the audio interface headphone jack.

Comment: Have you tried making sure the "pad" button is not engaged, setting to "line," and adjusting the gain control up until it clips (the clip light illuminates) and then back down slightly? Probably don't crank the amp to 11.

Comment: Thank you for your reply and yes I did try your suggestions. Some noise and I can hear just a tiny bit of guitar.  I hear Transcribe clear as day.  I suspect that connect amp headphone to the audio interface isn't possible for some audio technical reason I'm ignorant of.  What I know about audio you can stick in your eye with little or no irritation.

Comment: have you confirmed headphone-out on the amp works and is attenuated using the amp volume control?

Comment: Headphone -out works and volume is down.  I think that my problem has something to do with my using a mono jack  in the amp and the audio interface because if I pull the plug partly out of the amp I get sound in the left side of the headphone.

Comment: Are you saying the amp headphone jack is stereo and the audio interface is mono and you're using a stereo cable to connect them? I'm not entirely certain, but I could see where that might cause phase cancellation, which would explain the problem you're having. You need some kind of stereo to mono adapter (either a specially designed cable, or a plug with stereo female and mono male).

Comment: right, if one were to use a stereo-to-mono adapter and plugged a stereo cable into the mono side one would lose one channel (as far as I know). Try a "female stereo to male mono" adapter. Should be about 5$

Answer (score 1):

Basically what's happening here is that, like ScottM pointed out in the comments, you're trying to use a TS cable to connect a TRS jack to a TS jack.

More info on the distinction between these cables can be found here: https://www.sweetwater.com/sweetcare/articles/whats-the-difference-between-ts-and-trs-cables/

This is why you are hearing more volume when you pull the cable partially out, you are aligning the ring at the very tip of the TS cable to the second (lower) ring of the TRS jack. You can see clearly on the tips of the cables where the rings are, and this should correspond to the distance you have to pull it out to get more sound.

The two options you have are:

- Keep using a TS cable pulled out slightly. This is an option, but perhaps not sustainable, as any unplanned movement of the cable (someone stepping on it, cabinet vibration, etc) can cause your signal to be interrupted. This would only be a viable scenario in a studio setting with a seated player, and only for a short time.
- Get a TS-to-TRS converter. This will allow the connection to be made when the cables are fully plugged in. The only downside here (which is also a downside of option 1) is that the stereo signal from the headphone jack on your amp will be converted to mono going into your interface, due to the lack of stereo wiring in the TS end. You'll have to experiment to see how this affects your sound, and which channel is preserved.

Hopefully this helps!